# Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just wonder what are the standard units of measure in Gazebo? Is there anything like ROS [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) to standardize the units?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8497/standard-units-of-measure-and-coordinate-conventions-in-gazebo/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2015-04-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As far as I know, there's no complete documentation like the ROS REP 103.

In general, Gazebo uses [SI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) units, for example:

- length: meter (m)
- mass: kilogram (Kg)
- time: second (s)
- angle: radian ([gazebo::math::Angle::Degree()](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1math_1_1Angle.html#a10a0c78fdec2745bd59d1330ab50548f) to convert to degrees)
- force: Newton (N)

Coordinate frames are right-handed, with `Z` up, `X` forward and `Y` to the left.

Euler angles follow the roll (about X axis), pitch (about Y axis), yaw (about Z axis) order about a fixed reference frame.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on 2019-06-19**:
So, If I have 0.1 of length, it means that it is 0.1 meters. Is that correct? Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-06-19**:
Correct! ;)